# Add a GridPane to a ScrollPane using code javafx

Tags: javafx, scrollpane, gridpane

Please how can I add a GridPane to a ScrollPane that I have in my fxml file with javafx code ?

Answer (score 1):

If your `ScrollPane` has been defined in an `FXML` file, you need to add a reference to it within your `Controller` class. This is done along with any other instance fields you need to define (at the top of your controller class).  Since the node is defined in an `FXML` document, you will annotate your Java code with the `@FXML` annotation:

```
@FXML
private ScrollPane myScrollPane;
```

This essentially tells JavaFX that the `ScrollPane` is created in the `FXML` document, and not within your Java class.

The `ScrollPane` has a `Content` property that holds the node you want.

So you would simply set your `GridPane` as the `Content` of the `ScrollPane`:

`scrollPane.setContent(myGridPane);`

Comment: That didn't work, is there a property that I should add to be able to populate a scrollPane that I already have in My fxml file?

Comment: My answer addresses exactly that... What about my answer doesn't work? Maybe you need to update your question to show more code.